# Border color for input in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve such an effect as here https://zapodaj.net/c0e251a5b8ff2.png.html My current code looks like this
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQWvwJ So I'm trying for input

```
<div class="form-group has-warning" id="form-username">
   <label class="control-label" for="username">Your username</label>
   <input name="username" id="username" type="text" maxlength="36" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

add a class `has-warning` to change the color, but it does not. I'm using Bootstrap 4.0.0.

How do you set a border for the input field?

Comment: can you post your javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You also need to add `form-control-warning` to the input:

```
<div class="form-group has-warning" id="form-username">
   <label class="control-label" for="username">Your username</label>
   <input name="username" id="username" type="text" maxlength="36" class="form-control form-control-warning" />
</div>
```

Any element with `form-control-warning` inside `has-warning` (i.e., `.has-warning .form-control-warning` is what gets the border.

---

After taking a closer look, it actually looks like they changed the form validation stuff pretty drastically between `4.0-alpha6` (which is the documentation that references `has-warning` and `4.0` (which is the one in your CodePen). The new documentation can be found here: [Bootstrap 4 Form Validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation).

It looks like they got rid of the "warning" state entirely. It's now either valid or invalid. You have to then either use `was-validated` on a parent element, which then uses the pseudo-elements `:valid` and `:invalid` (based on HTML5 `required` and other things), or leave off `was-validated` and just add `is-invalid` directly to the `input` to get a red border. There is no yellow.

```
<div class="form-group" id="form-username">
  <label class="control-label" for="username">Your username</label>
  <input name="username" id="username" type="text" maxlength="36" class="form-control is-invalid" />
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxOvEL)

If you want to just color the border, I'd recommend you just apply the CSS. If you want to actually do the valid/invalid thing, I'd recommend going with the approach I just mentioned above. You could override the color to be that yellow-ish with this if you wanted:

```
.custom-select.is-invalid, .form-control.is-invalid, .was-validated .custom-select:invalid, .was-validated .form-control:invalid {
    border-color: #f0ad4e;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXeoVd)

Finally, though I don't recommend it, you could also just use the Bootstrap 4 Alpha version: `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css`. Though, I would avoid this since you're locking yourself to an already outdated version with newer code.

Comment: I did as you wrote, but it did not work. https://zapodaj.net/2605ee5d4b381.png.html

Comment: That should do the trick from what I'm seeing. Do you have any other CSS that might be conflicting? Can you try to set up an example in something like a Code Snippet on SO, or JSFiddle or Code Pen and see if you can replicate the problem? You can pull in the CDN version of Bootstrap 4 with any of those.

Comment: I gave the address to CodePen in the question. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQWvwJ

Comment: Oops, my bad. Sorry about that. Let me take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Simply You can change the border color by adding and removing the border-danger class dynamically using javascript.

```
const element = document.getElementById('username')
element.classList.add('border-danger');
```

To simply remove the border.

```
if(element.classList.contains('border-danger') {
  element.classList.remove('border-danger')
}
```